# Response codes in RESTful API

Tags: http, rest, response

If I have the following REST API:

/resource/{id}

where the id's are hashes of specific information.
If it is accessed with an id that is not "correct" e.g. 'abc' (/resource/abc),

Should this result in a 404 not found or should i result in something else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be a 404 if you're attempting a queryless GET. You're specifying a resource path that cannot be found, and this is what a 404 signifies.

If you're trying to get with bad query params you might want a 400.

If you trying to query the resource with a method not supported, you might want 405.

Read [http status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and you should be able to decide what you really need.

Comment: This is what I thought. Just to clarify: Let's say that the id's were verified in the server (e.g. they need to have the following format <ENOCH-TIMESTAMP>-<HASHED-SOMETHING), would it still be a 404 when having an incorrect id or could it also be a 400 bad request?

Comment: @Aesthete: Exactly right. With one caveat - *if* the specified "id" is known to have existed but is no longer available then it would also be OK to return a 410 response.

Comment: When you identify resources like your example, **resource/id**, it either exists or it doesn't. If you have parameters to support your query and _they_ are bad, perhaps you need a 400.

Comment: @pka: No, "bad syntax" doesn't refer to the URL itself in the case of 400 responses - it refers to the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on http method you use.
`404 Not found` for `GET` request will be definitely ok.